# Open an excel file using COM and save it as .xml file

Tags: php, xml, excel, com

Im trying the following code:

```
<?php

    $workbook = "D:\b2\\test.XLS";
    $sheet = "Sheet1";

    #Instantiate the spreadsheet component.
        $ex = new COM("Excel.sheet") or Die ("Did not connect");

    #Get the application name and version    
        print "Application name:{$ex->Application->value}<BR>" ; 
        print "Loaded version: {$ex->Application->version}<BR>"; 

    #Open the workbook that we want to use.
        $wkb = $ex->application->Workbooks->Open($workbook) or Die ("Did not open");

    #Create a copy of the workbook, so the original workbook will be preserved.
        $ex->Application->ActiveWorkbook->SaveAs("D:\b2\Ourtest.xml");  
        #$ex->Application->Visible = 1; #Uncomment to make Excel visible.



    #Optionally, save the modified workbook
        $ex->Application->ActiveWorkbook->SaveAs("D:\Ourtest.xml");                      
    #Close all workbooks without questioning
        $ex->application->ActiveWorkbook->Close("False");    
        unset ($ex);

    ?>
```

This actually works and creates the Ourtest.xml file. But im getting characters like:

ÐÏà¡±á                >  þÿ                                þÿÿÿ
I have tried with SaveAs("D:\Ourtest.pdf") and it says the file has been corrupted or incorrectly decoded. 
Can anyone help me please?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by using

```
$ex->Application->ActiveWorkbook->SaveAs("D:\Ourtest.xml",46);
```

46 is the value for **xlXMLSpreadsheet** 
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are saving it as Excel Format. Check the Excel documentation for how to save it as an XML document - it might be a separate paramter to `SaveAs` or a different method alltogether (`Export*`).

**EDIT:** It seems `SaveAs` is the right method to use. Check the [msdn documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas(VS.80).aspx). You probably want to specify the second parameter `FileFormat`. Maybe setting it to the `XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet` value?

Comment: And the documentation is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214129.aspx

Comment: $ex->Application->ActiveWorkbook->SaveAs("D:\b2\Ourtest.xml",XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet ); 
Should it be like this?

Comment: $ex->Application->ActiveWorkbook->SaveAs("D:\Ourtest.xml",Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet); I have tried this but i get "unable to get the SaveAs property...."

Comment: Try outputing "Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet" - does that work? If not, use VBA to print the value of that constant and define that in PHP.